# Check the content after the "/" on a URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Lets say my URL is:

> http://example.com**/12434/example-post**

I want to check if the current URL contains something after the `"/"`, in other words, I wan't to check whether or not I'm at the homepage http://example.com

Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: Not 'with jQuery' as such, but definitely with plain JavaScript (jQuery, so far as I know doesn't make it any easier or offer methods to achieve this).

Comment: You do not need jQuery for this, raw Javascript will do.

Comment: @Tadeck: You mean you don't do this? `$($(window).prop('location')).prop('pathname')` :D

Comment: @amnotiam: Excellent example, a lot easier than `location.pathname` or `window.location.pathname`, and everything is a lot faster in jQuery than in JavaScript. I am not sure why JavaScript is still being used when you have jQuery ;)

Comment: @Tadeck: Exactyl. All teh best codez are Jquery!!!!! :D

Answer (score 8):

Check `location` global object. It has [`pathname` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-location-pathname):

```
alert( location.pathname );
```

Comment: But for homepage, location.pathname = "what?"

Comment: @Belohlavek: Can't you test it? Just use the code @@dfsq gave you in his answer.

Comment: If you on the page `http://example.com/` then location.pathname will be `"/"`. If say you are on the page `http://example.com/user/edit/2` then location.pathname `"/user/edit/2"`, etc. Just open console and check it on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href gives the url of page. Test the code

```
alert(window.location.href);
```

Does the URL contains anything afer abc.com/xyz i.e. xyz here can be tested with below code;

```
var url= window.location.href;
if(url.split("/").length>3){
  // It is not the home page. It is not xyz.com. It has something after /
} 
else{
  // you are on the home page.
}
```